# Querying a junction/link/bridge table, column data as header

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have a list of specialties (upwards of 20)

```
SpecialtyID  Description 
------------------------
1           Specialty1             
2           Specialty2
3           Specialty3
```

I have a list of providers (upwards of 50)

```
ProviderID  Name
------------------------
1           Tom             
2           Maria
3           Pat
```

Each provider can have multiple specialties, each specialty can have multiple providers - so a many to many relationship.

I have a junction/link/bridge table called SpecialtyProvider and if I simply query the link table with the following query, I get the table below.

```
SELECT SpecialtyID, ProviderID FROM SpecialtyProvider 

SpecialtyID  ProviderID
------------------------
1           1             
2           1
3           1
1           2             
2           2
3           3
```

What I would like to do, is pull out the data formatted like so:

```
SpecialtyID  ProviderID=1  ProviderID=2  ProviderID=3  ProviderID=x
-----------------------------------------------------------
1           true           true          NULL
2           true           true          NULL
3           true           NULL          true
```

Once I can format the data correctly, I'll be dumping this into an ASP ListView.

I am not quite sure how to proceed. I have read 100 posts about different variations of the PIVOT command, but where I don't have an aggregate function, I haven't been able to make any of the other examples/solutions/groupings make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pivot without using an aggregate, you can usually just use `MAX` (you're essentially taking the MAX of a single value, which is just that same value).

```
select SpecialtyID, case when [1] is not null then 'true' end 'ProviderID=1', 
                    case when [2] is not null then 'true' end 'ProviderID=2', 
                    case when [3] is not null then 'true' end 'ProviderID=3'
from (
    select s.SpecialtyID, s.Description, sp.ProviderID
    from Specialty s 
    join SpecialtyProvider sp on sp.SpecialtyID = s.SpecialtyID
    ) x
pivot(  
    MAX(Description)
    for ProviderID in ([1],[2],[3])
      ) pvt
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7dc94/1/0)

However, it's also possible to get the same results without using `PIVOT` at all:

```
select s.SpecialtyID, 
Max(case when sp.ProviderID = 1 then 'true' end) 'ProviderID=1',
Max(case when sp.ProviderID = 2 then 'true' end) 'ProviderID=2',
Max(case when sp.ProviderID = 3 then 'true' end) 'ProviderID=3'
from Specialty s 
join SpecialtyProvider sp on sp.SpecialtyID = s.SpecialtyID   
group by s.SpecialtyID
```

I find this easier to read, and it will probably be faster as well.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7dc94/2/0)

With all that said, you may want to reconsider your UI.  Having a table 50 columns wide will be difficult for a user to process.  It might make sense to filter the data so the user can only view specific portions of it.  Also, if you're dealing with a variable number of providers, it may make sense to pull all the data up to the web server and process it in your ASP codebehind.

Comment: This is a perfect solution, thank you. However, I think what is probably even more helpful is your comment about reconsidering the UI. The birth of the problem scenario was someone dropping a spreadsheet on my desk and saying, "make something just like this" and I got caught up in trying to do just that vs. really looking at the best way to serve the underlying information given the medium.

Answer (score 1):

The following blog post introduces the concept of a dynamic pivot where you do not have to specify you columns so as to address the X factor for Providers.  http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10840/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

I took it a bit further and also print out the generated SQL.  Here is what I came up for to address your example above.

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'dynamic_pivot', N'P') IS NOT NULL) 
DROP PROCEDURE dynamic_pivot
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic_pivot
(
  @select VARCHAR(2000)
, @PivotCol VARCHAR(100)
, @Summaries VARCHAR(100)
, @GenerateScript BIT = 1
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON ;
DECLARE @pivot VARCHAR(MAX)
  , @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @select = REPLACE(@select, 'SELECT ',
                          'SELECT ' + @PivotCol + ' AS pivot_col, ')


CREATE TABLE #pivot_columns
(
  pivot_column VARCHAR(100)
)

SELECT  @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT pivot_col FROM (' + @select + ') AS t'

INSERT  INTO #pivot_columns
        EXEC ( @sql
            )

SELECT  @pivot = COALESCE(@pivot + ',', '') + '[' + pivot_column + ']'
FROM    #pivot_columns

SELECT  @sql = '
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    ' + @select + '
) AS t 
PIVOT 
(
    ' + @Summaries + ' for pivot_col in (' + @pivot + ')
) AS p' 
 PRINT @sql
 EXEC(@sql) 
END
GO

EXEC [dbo].[dynamic_pivot] @select = 'SELECT SpecialtyID, 1 AS hasSpecialty FROM SpecialtyProvider', -- varchar(2000)
@PivotCol = 'ProviderID', -- varchar(100)
@Summaries = 'COUNT(hasSpecialty)' -- varchar(100)
```

The resulting query that is displayed in your message window in SSMS is the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT ProviderID AS pivot_col, SpecialtyID, 1 AS hasSpecialty FROM SpecialtyProvider
) AS t 
PIVOT 
(
    COUNT(hasSpecialty) for pivot_col in ([1],[2],[3])
) AS p
```

You can modify this to give you the column names and values that are required.